# Why adding items to map during its iteration produce inconsistent result?

Tags: go

From [Go Spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements):

> If map entries are created during iteration, that entry may be produced during the iteration or may be skipped.

So what I expect from that statement is that the following code should at least print number `1`, and how many more numbers which are going to be printed is not predictable and is different each time you run the program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    test := make(map[int]int)

    test[1] = 1
    j := 2
    for i, v := range test {
        fmt.Println(i, v)
        test[j] = j
        j++
    }

    return

}
```

[Go playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/beYoOumZdY)

On my own laptop (Go version 1.8) at maximum it prints till `8`, in playground (still version 1.8) it prints exactly till `3`!
I don't care much about the result from playground since its go is not [vanilla](https://blog.golang.org/playground) but I wonder why on my local it never prints more than `8`? even I tried to add more items in each iteration to make the possibility of going over `8` higher but there's no difference.

**EDIT: my own explanation based on @Schwern 's answer**

when the map is created with `make` function and without any size parameter only 1 bucket is assigned and in go each bucket has a size of 8 elements, so when the range starts it sees that the map has only 1 bucket and it will iterate at maximum 8 times. If I use a size parameter bigger than 7 like `make(map[int]int, 8)` two buckets is created and there would be possibility that I get more than 8 iterations over the added items.

Comment: My educated guess is that `test := make(map[int]int)` builds a map that has room for 8 key-value pairs. After that, Go has to create a new backing array so the copy stored in the for loop is exhausted and code execution exits the loop.

Comment: Note that the Go Playground uses a fixed setting for its random function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue inherent in the design of most hash tables. Here's a simple explanation hand waving a lot of unnecessary detail.

Under the hood, a hash table is an array. Each key is mapped onto an element in the array using a [hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution). For example, "foo" might map to element 8, "bar" might map to element 4, and so on. Some elements are empty.

`for k,v := range hash` iterates through this array in whatever order they happen to appear. The ordering is unpredictable to avoid a [collision attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_attack).

When you add to a hash, it adds to the underlying array. It might even have to allocate a new, larger array. It's unpredictable where that new key will land in the hash's array.

So if you add more pairs while you're iterating through the hash, any pair that gets put into the array before the current index won't be seen; the iteration has already past that point. Anything that gets put after *might* be seen; the iteration has yet to reach that point, but the array might get reallocated and the pairs possibly rehashed.

> *but I wonder why on my local it never prints more than 8*

Because the underlying array is probably of length 8. Go likely allocates the underlying array in powers of 2 and probably starts at 8. The `range hash` probably starts by checking the length of the underlying array and will not go further, even if it's grown.

Long story short: don't add keys to a hash while iterating through it.

Comment: got my answer: "Because the underlying array is probably of length 8", if I create the map with a size parameter in make function with a number bigger than `7` it starts to print more than 8 items (of course randomly).